# How to make icon appear in desktop entry?

Tags: icons, themes, xfce

**Tldr;** the icon I've added in the `.icons` folder of my home doesn't appear in my desktop entry, but if I choose another icon already present in the folder, it shows. Why? And how can I make my icon show?

I use xfce.

I have installed [Qogir icon theme](https://github.com/vinceliuice/Qogir-icon-theme), so I have in my home a `.icons` folder with several Qogir folders :

```
├── Qogir
├── Qogir-dark
├── Qogir-manjaro
├── Qogir-manjaro-dark
├── Qogir-ubuntu
└── Qogir-ubuntu-dark
```

I have selected Qogir manjaro dark icon theme, where most of the folders actually link to Qogir manjaro. This works find. [Screenshot of selected icon theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXrBl.png)

My problem is, I wanted to add a new icon to the desktop entry (that I've created) of Molotov app. My desktop file (in `~/.local/share/applications/molotov.desktop`) :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Molotov
GenericName=Molotov
Comment=Application pour regarder la télévision
Exec=~/Documents/Applications/molotov.AppImage  
Terminal=false
Icon=molotov
Type=Application
Categories=Video;
```

I've put a `molotov.svg` icon in every Qogir folder possible, but it doesn't show. If I change `Icon=molotov` to `Icon=firefox-trunk`, the Firefox icon shows. But even if they're in the same directory, my molotov icon doesn't show. When I right-click on the desktop entry (in my "favorites" list) > Modify the app, and try to change the icon from there, every icon shows, but not the molotov one. But if go into the different Qogir folders from my folder manager, it's there ! [Screenshot of molotov icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZswD.png)

And the molotov icon doesn't have less rights than the firefox-trunk one.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 chloe chloe   5259 déc.   5  2019 firefox-trunk.svg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chloe chloe  34307 mars  23 20:12 molotov.svg
```

Do you know why molotov icon won't appear in the desktop entry?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why the icon doesn't appear in the icons list, however I've found a solution: I changed it thanks to [MenuLibre](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/menulibre), which allows (among other things) to change the desktop entry icon by selecting a specific file.